# Create a base project using Angular JS with CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter

I'm starting to study AngularJS and I need to create a base code to create a website using angularJS with Codeigniter.

Someone of you guys have a example projects using AngularJS+CodeIgniter?

Comment: Really makes little difference what back end framework you use. There is no dependence between back and front end

Answer (score 1):

My proposal is separate applications.

---

- Client - Angular.JS,
- Server - PHP (CodeIgniter).

Communication between applications is via HTTP Requests.
So, your PHP application may be REST API.